# Craft 3 entry.author.getPhoto() is coming up null on template, but the author has a photo uploaded in the user > details section, any ideas why?

Tags: craft3, templating, custom-field

The site is utilizing a Servd bucket to store all assets. The backend shows a photo successfully uploaded to the user > details section, but does not provide a url in the entry.author.getPhoto(), it comes up null. The photoId is also null (screenshots from the {% dd entry.author %} is provided below). Has anyone had this problem before and how did you solve it? I've tried other iterations including entry.getAuthor().getPhoto(), entry.author.photo. I've even used the author id to query for the user object and the photo is null there too. The photo is showing under custom fields on the dump, is there some alternative way I need to grab the photo on the template?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]